# Which Distributed File System as a backend for Cloud Computing?

Tags: centos, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Distributed File System as a backend for Cloud Computing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/36065/which-distributed-file-system-as-a-backend-for-cloud-computing)

I have a cloud running on CentOS 5.5 with Eucalyptus2 loaded.The thing is can we integrate some other file system like Parallel file system or Linux ext2fs filesystems into the walrus.
Have anyone tried or implemented like this before??If so,please provide the details.Open to any suggestions...